# How to display full error in asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've started with an asp.net mvc 3 and I have a problem, with some error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Movies

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225
```

I know what it means but I know sure if it is a true.

I want to get a full Yellow Screen of Death.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is something wrong with you routes. Check the global.asax file to see if the url paths are configured correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think the routing data might not be set correctly.  People often make this mistake  with asp.net mvc. You can download the [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to find out why the path you requested cannot be found.